# Get all pixels of an Image [Wand]

Tags: python-3.x, wand

I am using the [Wand Python Library](https://wand.readthedocs.org/en/0.4.0/index.html), and trying to solve the [Python Challenge](http://pythonchallenge.com), and my current problem asks me to get all even/odd pixels.

This is, obviously, a very simple task. However, I found the Wand library quite slow in loading pixels/copying pixels (Maybe it's because I also change fill_color to the color of the pixel for each?), and I was wondering if I could just load them all in at once.

My current solution to loading all pixels is something like this:

```
from wand.image import Image
img = Image(filename="5808.jpg")
pixels = []
for x in range(img.width+1):
    for y in range(img.height+1):
        pixels.append(img[x, y])

print(pixels)
```

I'd prefer something like this:

```
from wand.image import Image
img = Image(filename="5808.jpg")
print(img.pixels)
```

Is there anything akin to that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without attempting to read the Python Challenge, and just focusing on the question..

> I'd prefer something like this: `img.pixels`

Iterating over the image size to collect `wand.color.Color` objects would be slow as this invokes repeated uses of MagickWand's internal pixel iteration & pixel structure. As said challenge is for Python, and not C buffers, I'd recommend getting a buffer of pixel data once. After which your freely able to iterate, compare, evaluate, & etc. without need of ImageMagick resource.

For this example, I'm assuming the images is a 2x2 PNG below *(scaled for visibility.)*

[image: Example 2x2 PNG]

```py
from wand.image import Image

# Prototype local variables
pixels = []
width, height = 0, 0
blob = None

# Load image
with Image(filename='2x2.png') as image:
    # Enforce pixels quantum between 0 & 255
    image.depth = 8
    # Save width & height for later use
    width, height = image.width, image.height
    # Copy raw image data into blob string
    blob = image.make_blob(format='RGB')

# Iterate over blob and collect pixels
for cursor in range(0, width * height * 3, 3):
    # Save tuple of color values
    pixels.append((blob[cursor],      # Red
                   blob[cursor + 1],  # Green
                   blob[cursor + 2])) # Blue
print(pixels)
#=> [(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 128, 0), (255, 255, 255)]
```

This example is pretty quick, but remember Python does objects very well. Let's extend the `Image` object, and create the method to satisfy `img.pixels`.

```py
# Lets create a generic pixel class for easy color management
class MyPixel(object):
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0
    def __init__(self, red=0, green=0, blue=0):
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'#{0.red:02X}{0.green:02X}{0.blue:02X}'.format(self)

# Extend wand.image.Image and add a new `img.pixels` pseudo-attribute
class MyImage(Image):
    # Repeat above example
    @property
    def pixels(self):
        pixels = []
        self.depth = 8
        blob = self.make_blob(format='RGB')
        for cursor in range(0, self.width * self.height * 3, 3):
            pixel = MyPixel(red=blob[cursor],
                            green=blob[cursor + 1],
                            blue=blob[cursor + 2])
            pixels.append(pixel)
        return pixels

# Call your custom class; which, collects your custom pixels
with MyImage(filename=filename) as img:
    print(img.pixels)
#=> [#FF0000, #0000FF, #008000, #FFFFFF]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I ever find myself using Wand, i will use this, but I've managed to get **Pillow** to work. (The only reason I used Wand was because Pillow wasn't available.)